# MySQL, two columns both set to the primary key

Tags: mysql

For the sake of simplicity lets say I have a table with 3 columns;  `id`, `parent_id` and `name`. In this table `id` is my auto-incrementing primary key.  I want to group multiple names together in this table, to do this all names in a group will share the same `parent_id`.   If I am inserting the first name in the group I want the `id`=`parent_id`,  if i am inserting another name I want to specify a specific parent_id to place that name into a specific group.  It would be nice if I could define a *default* for that column to be the same as the id, if I specify a value for `parent_id` in the insert query then I would like it to use that value.   I know you can set a default to be a specific static value,  but can you specify the default to be the same as that row's auto-incrementing primary key?  Perhaps this is a job for a trigger or stored procedure?

(I know I could obtain the primary key generated by the last insert and then update the table, but that's 2 quires I'd rather not burn.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job of a trigger!

```
CREATE TRIGGER NAME1 AFTER INSERT ON TABLE1 
BEGIN

UPDATE TABLE1 SET parent_id = id WHERE (parent_id IS NULL OR parent_id = '');

END;

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id,parent_id) VALUES (null,null); -- parent_id will be equal to id
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id,parent_id) VALUES (null,'1'); -- parent_id will be 1
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id,parent_id) VALUES (null,'2'); -- parent_id will be 2
```